# Why is the action in which a Windows registry file is saved on the HDD is called a "HIVE"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, windows-10, windows-registry

I am curious to find out what was the logic behind this naming. Most concepts in IT have names that actually means something related to that specific concept in real world but I am not able to find the logic behind this particular name.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "hive" is actually a bit of joke that originated within Microsoft:

> Because one of the original developers of Windows NT hated bees.  So the developer who was responsible for the registry snuck in as many bee references as he could.  A registry file is called a "hive", and registry data are stored in "cells", which is what honeycombs are made of.

(Source: [Why is a registry file called a “hive”?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030808-00/?p=42943))

Answer (score 0):

#### I am curious to find out what was the logic behind this naming.

> **Useless trivia day.**
>
> Why is a registry file called a "hive"?
>
> Because one of the original developers of Windows NT hated bees.  So
>   the developer who was responsible for the registry snuck in as many
>   bee references as he could.  A registry file is called a "hive", and
>   registry data are stored in "cells", which is what honeycombs are made
>   of.

Source [Why is a registry file called a “hive”?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030808-00/?p=42943) by Raymond Chen of Microsoft.

Comment: posting the same what was already posted by an user makes no real sense

Comment: @magicandre1981 Our answers were pretty much posted at the same time (mine was 90 seconds later) :/

Comment: before you post an answer you get notified about new answers. here you already saw that someone else posted the SAME like you.

Comment: @magicandre1981 <shrug> I don't get such notifications. Or the top bar ones (unless I reload the page). Some issue with a FF script ... feel free to delete my answer if it really bothers you.

Comment: I can't delete answers, I'm no moderator.